# Display Tree Like Menu without recursive function

Tags: php, hierarchical-data

My Table Looks Like

```
ID | Parent    | Name    | Level
 1 | 0         | Cat1    | 0
 2 | 1         | SubCat1 | 1
 3 | 0         | Cat2    | 0
 4 | 3         | SubCat2 | 1
 5 | 4         | SubCat3 | 2
 6 | 3         | SubCat4 | 3
```

I need to display the data in the order:

```
 Cat1
      SubCat1
 Cat2
      Subcat2
          SubCat3
      SubCat4
```

I'm able to perform it well with recursive function but the requirement now is to do without recursive function. Kindly help, i'm quite confused with the level field too.

Code to fetch from db:

```
class Sitemap
{ 


public static function getTopCategories()
{
    return self::getCategories('parent=0');
}

public static function getCategories($where='')
{
    if ($where) $where = " WHERE $where";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sitemap $where");

    $categories = array();
   //while ($category = mysql_fetch_object($result, 'Category'))
    while ($category = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $my_id = $category['id'];

    $category['children'] = Sitemap::getCategories("parent = $my_id");

            $categories[] = $category;
        }

     mysql_free_result($result);
    return $categories;
  }


 }
```

Code to display(Using Smarty):

```
{foreach from=$sitemap item=c name=sitemap}
 {if $c.parent ==0 }
<li><h2><a title="{$c.name}" href="{$c.url}">{$c.name}</a></h2><ul>
    {foreach item=d from=$c.children name=sitemap} 
<li><a title="{$d.name}" href="{$d.url}">{$d.name}</a></li>
    {/foreach}
{else}  
<li><h2><a title="{$c.name}" href="{$c.url}">{$c.name}</a></h2><ul>
{/if}
</ul>
</li>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: What code do you have? What research did you do? How do you think it should work? What have you tried?

Comment: I have done the research on stackoverflow n didnt find any help so i asked here... Regarding the code, i m using two foreach loop to display the cat n sub cat.. however I'm able to get in only upto two levels

Comment: The table is in a DB ? How do you get it ? Put a sample of your code if you want help.

Comment: Updated, please have a look at it now, kindly remove the negative point for the question so that I can get a answer for it.

Comment: Do i need to post anything else or this is enough?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try this :->


 with recursive function

 function menu ($p_id='0')
 {

     $q1="select * from menu where p_id='$p_id'";
     $r1=mysql_query($q1) or die(mysql_error());
     while($s1=mysql_fetch_array($r1))
       {
          echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$s1['name']."=>";
          $q2="select * from menu where p_id='$s1[id]'";
          $r2=mysql_query($q2) or die(mysql_error()."2nd query error");
          $ro2=mysql_num_rows($r2);
          if($ro2>0)
          {
             $p_id=$s1['id'];
             menu($p_id);
          }

         echo "<br/>";
     }

 }



   echo menu();
```

without recursive function ::

```
You have to use procedure language like this

<ul>
    <?php
    $query="select * from table where pid='0'";
     $q1=mysql_query($query);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($q1))
     {
        echo "<li>$row[pname]
          // 2nd step check and wirite query and diplay and so on
     <echo "</li>"; 
     }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry while loop cannot be used with the current problem..please refer smarty